# How do I distribute test doubles with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

I'm creating a pod that defines a Swift protocol, and several implementations of that protocol.

I would also like to distribute a test double (i.e. mock, stub, spy, etc.) implementation of the protocol for projects to use in their tests, when using my pod.

Can I configure my pod to include my test double source files only in the test target of the project using my pod?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of [subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) and [`default_subspec`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#tab_default_subspecs) to set this up for your clients.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name = "MyPod"
  spec.default_subspec = 'Library'

  spec.subspec "Library" do |subspec|
    subspec.source_files = "src/*.swift"
    // ... other cocoapods configuration commands
  end
  spec.subspec "TestDoubles" do |subspec|
    subspec.source_files = "testdoubles/*.swift"
    // ... other cocoapods configuration commands
  end
end
```

To import the library in your clients' Podfile they can still use this syntax:

```
pod 'MyPod'
```

And to import the test doubles, they can use this syntax:

```
pod 'MyPod/TestDoubles'
```